# Based on my previous qu-How to perform some actions on each value from a drop down using selenium java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Now I want to select first value from a drop down then perform some actions on it, then I want to select second value from the same drop down and perform the same action on it.
Here is my code:

```
WebElement bldgs=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("Bldgselect"));
Select  Bldg_select=new Select(bldgs);

List<WebElement> dropdownvalues = Bldg_select.getOptions();

int count=dropdownvalues.size();

System.out.println("Total number of values are :"+count);

for(int i=1;i<count;i++) {

  if(dropdownvalues.get(i).isEnabled()) {
    Bldg_select.selectByIndex(i);

    System.out.println("Not Working :"+i);

    waitForWebPagetoLoad(2000);

    WebElement search_BTN=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("search_Btn"));
    fn_Click(search_BTN);


    WebElement  add_VEND=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("add_vendors"));
    fn_Click(add_VEND);

    WebElement  vendorName=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("vendor_Name"));
    fn_Click(vendorName);

    vendorName.sendKeys(vendor);

    waitForWebPagetoLoad(5000);

    WebElement  search_BTN1=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("search_Btn"));
    fn_Click(search_BTN1);

    WebElement  selectVendor=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("select_Vendor"));
    fn_Click(selectVendor);

    WebElement  addToSite=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("AddTo_Site"));
    fn_Click(addToSite);

    }
}
```

here I am seaching for an element(basically drop down id) and then selecting each value with selectbyindex with i for loop. and then I am clicking on a button and performing some more actions on it. Now it is selecting only first value and doing all above stuff. But it is not going back in for loop to select 2nd value and performs same steps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below solution? I am not sure what action you are tryig to execute based on selection but I think below code solve your problem.

```
     Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Locator")));

        List <WebElement> elementCount = drpCountry.getOptions();
        int iSize = elementCount.size();

        for(int i =0; i<iSize ; i++)
        {
            String sValue = elementCount.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(sValue);
            drpCountry.selectByIndex(i);

                    if(sValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Selection1")){  
                    //code to be executed if condition1 is true  
                    }else if(sValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Selection2")){  
                    //code to be executed if condition2 is true  
                    }  
                    else if(sValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Selection3")){  
                    //code to be executed if condition3 is true  
                    }  

                    else{  
                    //code to be executed if all the conditions are false  
                    }  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem butI can see 2 issues that may be adding to confusion.

### **Index should 0 based**

Your loop is starting with i set to 1.  As lists are zero based indexes, you should start at 0

### **Referencing stale elements??**

You are extracting the dropdown values outside of the loop and then referencing these within the loop using index.  However, you are performing a lot of actions and events within each iteration.

You may be better extracting the values again within each iteration to ensure all your references are up to date and have not gone stale.